# Add BaseGameUtils to Android project by command line

Tags: java, android, ant, command-line, delphi

I'm developing Android apps without Eclipse or Android Studio. I use Lazarus+ZenGL (Object Pascal) to build a library loaded into a "fake" project.

All is working well, also Google Play Services for admob. If I need native calls, I can add these into the mainActivity.java file.

So I haven't an Eclipse project neither for Android Studio and I need to do everything (about compiling and building apk) by command line. This is not a big problem: a batch file does everything I need: aapt, javac, dx, android update, ant release, jarsigner and zipalign.

About Google Play Services I copied google-play-services.jar into my libs directory and updated project.properties with the right path:

```
...
android.library.reference.1=../../../../Android/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib
...
```

The problem is that Google Play Services has his own jar, that I pass also into javac options, but BaseGameUtils has not.

I tried to follow tutorials, but no one explain how to add BaseGameUtils (and libs without jar) to a project by command line (updating project.properties with BaseGameUtils is not enough).

Without this lib I can't "import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity;" into mainActivity.java

I hope this is clear enough, I'm quite new about android dev and I'm using a very alternative way...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just a comment for future viewers: You should not add or copy "only the jar" if you are planning to use any resource (images, text, etc) from the Google Play Services (If I'm not wrong, error messages are included as resources).